# How to create a customized layout

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

i'm creating an app, and i'm kinda knew in android develpment, i don't have much experience, but i've bee maneging well. My app is almost complete and now i want to improve the looks. 
Anyone knows how to put the widgets inside boxes, separated from background ? Like, i'll give you an example:
[image: Costumized look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone knows how to put the widgets inside boxes, separated from
>   background ?

=> You can use the [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) provided in support library. `CardView` is nothing but a `FrameLayout` so you can include whatever views inside it!

For more reference, go through the [Creating Lists and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Comment: And the CardView can be in a linear layout, or has to be in a frameLayout ?

Comment: @CésarPereira It need not be in a particular layout! As mentioned in the answer, CardView itself extends FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Use frame layouts for the boxes.

Comment: Please provide more explanation for your answer.

Comment: But for the box, i have to pass it in like in an image ? and then put the widgets i want on top of the image ?